# Schema drop-down options in swagger running under the Delphi MVC framework

Tags: delphi, swagger-ui

Hi  I am using the Delphi MVC framework. With a https connection.  How do I remove the http option from the swagger - schemes drop down OR how can I get the drop down to default to https?

Comment: Which MVC framework are you referring to?

Comment: delphimvcframework    https://github.com/danieleteti/delphimvcframework

Comment: [This line](https://github.com/danieleteti/delphimvcframework/blob/6837182cc3925508c48d32a78669e8fb1c511162/sources/MVCFramework.Middleware.Swagger.pas#L294) seems to be responsible for populating the drop-down list. Currently I see no other option but modifying DelphiMVCFramework sources (removing `tpsHttp` from returned schemes set). Since `TMVCSwaggerMiddleware.DocumentApiSettings` is a private method you can't do that in a derived class. You should ask the author to add an option that gives you control over supported schemes (ideally by introducing a property in `TMVCSwaggerMiddleware`).